# Insert Bulk data into SQL Server from membase?

Tags: membase

I am using Membase Server 1.7.0. bulk of data is inserted in membase, parallel I want it to insert in SQL Server also.

What are my best options to bulk load data as quickly as possible into SQL Server from Membase Server using any existing tools? Can I use some csv/other format which can just read data and store in SQL Server tables?

Please Suggest.

Comment: through SSIS we can copy a table from a database to an other database but from membase server to sql databae how can i do tat please explain it..

Comment: Does membase have an ODBC driver?

Comment: There is currently no ODBC driver for Membase.

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want to do here is use the TAP API that Membase provides. The TAP API allows you to stream all key-value pairs out of your database so for each key you read from the stream you can just do an insert into your SQL database. There is currently support for TAP in spymemcached 2.7.1, the java client for memcached/membase.